# Passing variable from view to the controller without query string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm fairly sure I'm missing something very practical but I'm floundering at finding it online.

**How do you pass information from the view to the controller without using URL items (query strings, /variable/ etc?**

The easiest scenario I can think that surely must have an example is a simple set of login credentials handed to a controller. Naturally you wouldn't want the username / password to be viewable in the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can POST data to the controller, so that it doesn't appear in the URL. See this [blog post](http://ubiquitous-tech.blogspot.com/2009/05/aspnet-mvc-post-to-controllers.html) for details.

The basic steps are:

1. Create a form on the view and name the fields in which you are interested.
2. Create an action on the controller whose parameters match those names.
3. Add the `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` attribute to the action.